# invalid operands of types что делать?

Tags: c++, числа-с-плавающей-точкой

Добрый день. Проблема в чем? - выдает ошибку: 
    "invalid operands of types 'double' and 'double(const char*) throw()' to binary 'operator=='"
Вот фрагмент кода, в котором выдает ошибку:

```
double Opredel(){
int swapc= triangulat();
double opredel=mat[0][0];
for(int i=1;i<size;i++){
  mat[i][i]= 0;
  opredel*=mat[i][i];
}
if(swapc % 2 != 0 ){
  opredel *=-1;
}
if(opredel == nan){
  opredel = 0;
}
return opredel;
}
```

Если будет не сложно, то объясните почему возникает эта ошибка, чтобы впредь таких не совершать. Спасибо.

Comment: Мой хрустальный шар подсказывает, что `nan` является функцией и вы забыли дописать скобочки, чтобы вызвать ее.

Comment: Дело в том что при расчете определителя иногда возникает значение nan в ячейках матрици . И я хочу проверять что если из за этого весь определитель превращается в nan то просто преобразовать его в 0.(вызов как функцию попробывал, выползла другая ошибка).

Comment: Так вы определитесь, что такое `nan` и что вы собираетесь с ним сделать.

Comment: Так я и определился. Мне нужно проверять значение определителя на то не равняется ли он nan.

Comment: @ВладЛесной: И? С чего вы взяли, что можно просто взять и написать `opredel == nan`?

Comment: Не поверишь но такая конструкция работала в другом файлике.

Comment: @Влад Лесной: Вы что-то выдумываете.

Comment: Скорее всего у вас подключён заголовочный файл `<cmath>`, а в нём имеется функция [`nan()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/nan). Функцию нельзя сравнивать с числом с плавающей точкой, о чём вам и сообщил компилятор.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сравнивать с NaN нельзя, это всегда `false` - по определению :)

Посмотрите на функцию `isnan`, или, как вариант - поскольку сравнение NaN всегда ложно - можно проверять вот так:

```
bool is_nan(double x) { return x != x; }
```

Только учтите, что не все компиляторы это все поддерживают (насколько я помню, Watcom что-то не так считал... но не помню, что) и второе - такая проверка - это говорит скорее о некорректности самого алгоритма...

Comment: Спасибо нашел в вычислениях деление на 0 устранил теперь эта проверка не нужна.